# In what ways can I test an image slideshow javascript code?

Tags: javascript, testing, visual-testing

I have a slideshow of images (and links) on a page. These images are part of a JSON response to a request sent after the page loads. The slideshow is set to play at an interval of 2 seconds. The slideshow can be paused, played over, and all other controls a normal slideshow would have.

As a Rails dev, I proposed cucumber but the javascript guys in the team are not comfortable with ruby. I saw some cucumber for javascript libraries coming up, still in experimental stage.

I checked out jasmine and related tutorials but all I could get from them is how I can carry out any internal functional testing such as credit-cart validation, etc. - which I think could actually be handled in unit testing?

(Screw the research I did and) How should I go about testing this and similar components?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a task for web testing tools:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_testing

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools

Check these, for example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir